# Simple if statement is failing

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I have this code where the value of *shopOpenHour* is @"0800" :

```
if([[shopOpenHour substringFromIndex: 2] isEqualToString: @"00"])
    minute = 0;
else
    minute = 30;
```

The *if* statement fails and hits the *else* statement instead.  I have tried using braces around the if and else statements, but makes no difference.

What's wrong with the *if* statement?

Comment: The `if` statement is fine - it is your assumptions that are incorrect.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the result of printing `[shopOpenHour substringFromIndex: 2]` and `[[shopOpenHour substringFromIndex: 2] length]`.

Comment: It's a valid question, so why all of the down votes? I admit I got carried away by including iOS8.1, but is that a reason for the downvote?  (I noticed you didn't know the answer to the question either).

Comment: Can you email me mentioned in my profile? we met [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747280/i-need-to-create-another-branch-from-a-past-commit/27747374#27747374). I want to know from you how to be a good programmer? some tricks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I could think of why this conditional would take the `else` branch is that `shopOpenHour` has additional non-printable characters, such as `\n`. They would prevent you from getting an exact match.

Using `substringWithRange:` and passing a range of length 2 should fix the problem:

```
if([[shopOpenHour substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 2)] isEqualToString: @"00"])
    minute = 0;
else
    minute = 30;
```

Comment: Unbelievable!  thank you so much... works like a champ!