# I need to create another branch from a past commit

Tags: git, xcode6.1

I have a Git repos that looks like this:

[image]

I want to create a new branch from the highlighted commit. (It's a long story, but basically I want to submit the iOS app while working out kinks in the latest branch).  I'm pretty sure this is possible, just don't know how to accomplish it... in addition, I don't see any way of using 'tags' in XCode 6.1.. is it available, just not documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as (Check [git-checkout(1) Manual Page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) documentation)

```
git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]
```

- `<start_point>`:

> The name of a commit at which to start the new branch; see [git-branch(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html) for details. Defaults to `HEAD`.

- `-b <new_branch>`:

> Create a new branch named `<new_branch>` and start it at `<start_point>`.

- `-B <new_branch>`:

> Creates the branch `<new_branch>` and start it at `<start_point>`; if it already exists, then reset it to `<start_point>`.